# How to change variables in a running program?

Tags: c++, messaging

For example I have a vector in my c++ program:

```
vector<string> files;
```

And this program is already running.

I want to invoke my other program to dynamically add a string to files vector (in already running program).

Should I make a client-server application on localhost for that?
Or are there other methods? (how to send message with params to the running program)

Comment: Boost.Interprocess comes to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give a great answer because I'm not experienced, but these are a few of the things I'm planning to look into:

- [Boost.ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)
- [Boost.interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)
- [YAMI](http://www.inspirel.com/yami4/)
- TCP or Unix sockets on the local host.
- File watching

Maybe something in there will be useful for you. Interprocess communication is the term you want to search for (IPC).

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to do this. Google for Inter process communication.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

On Windows I would use something like that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366551(v=vs.85).aspx

Or just a temporary file if I you want to be quick and dirty about it.